# Combine different angular programs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have used OnsenUI framework and programmed a simple program (see my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/xbEPyj))

in that program i have used `var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);`

Every factories and functions are based on `var module` and i don't have separate folders for directives or services or filters.

When I wanted to do parallax effect for my **detail.html** in my program using [this one](https://github.com/oblador/angular-parallax)

i became confused how to incorporate the concept in my program.

this program has `angular.module('myApp', ['duParallax'])` and three files under folders **directives/parallax.js, services/helper.js and module.js**

In parallax.js

```
angular.module('duParallax.directive', ['duScroll']).
directive('duParallax',
  function($rootScope, $window, $document, duParallaxTouchEvents){
...
}
```

In helper.js

```
angular.module('duParallax.helper', []).
factory('parallaxHelper',
  function() {
...
});
```

In module.js

```
angular.module('duParallax', ['duScroll', 'duParallax.directive', 'duParallax.helper']).value('duParallaxTouchEvents', true);
```

Any advice on how to make it work on my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's assume you have included the files

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oblador.github.io/angular-scroll/0.6.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oblador.github.io/angular-parallax/angular-parallax.min.js"></script>
```

Next, you must include it in your module, with:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['duParallax'])
```

Next, inject `parallaxHelper` in your controller (see [Angular Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)), and use `parallaxHelper.createAnimator(transition)`:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, parallaxHelper){
    $scope.background = parallaxHelper.createAnimator(-0.3);
  }
```

Finally, insert in your html the points you want to apply parallax, using the respective scope vars that you have used in the controller. In the previous case:

```
<section ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img src="img.png" du-parallax y="background" alt="" />
</section>
```

That should be all! Source: [Quick start guide](https://github.com/oblador/angular-parallax)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alex-j but i'm already using angular.module('app',['onsen']), so if i use myApp and duParallax instead of app and onsen, my entire program won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use both of them, and any other you want, just separate them with commas: `angular.module('app',['onsen', 'duParallax'])`

Comment: Nope, Not working, Included both onsen & duParallax, wrote a new [controller](http://varanjith.com/repo/image/1.png) and included all the [necessary files](http://varanjith.com/repo/image/2.png). The parallax effect is not working, though the program is working well.

Comment: am i missing something?

Comment: Ok, so both of them are running. Then it should be an issue of how to make duParallax working. Maybe you need to add something in the html or config something more in the controller. If you post it in plunkr or similar we can go deeper through your code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Alex-J, Here is the full working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/H8QnzclpOlxdBiPivcoQ). I have included both the controllers one from my own and the other from the plugin. Click login button and then swipe the landing page, select a category, click a product, the next page should show the parallax effect. but it isn't.

Comment: Hey @RanjithVaradan, I was looking at your code yesterday and trying to make it work (sorry for the delay, don't have so much time). I couldn't make it work. I've tried the [official example](http://oblador.github.io/angular-parallax/) (apart from your code) and it works. I suspect that is something about the structure html that you're using in onsen. In the official demo you can see the scrollbar, but not in your webpage. I think that's a tip, and somehow the plugin can't calculate the topScroll position.

Comment: If you inspect the img tag of your website that you apply the du-parralax, you'll see a style attribute with a translate sentence. That means that the plugin is working, but somehow it's not updating

Comment: Thanks @Alex-J. I'm trying with some other parallax plugins with no success. Will post an update when i found the right one.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't search for other plugins. As I said, the plugin is working, it would be the same for the other plugins. You should try to find what happen with the scroll position of the page. You can start testing using jquery, such as scrollTop and other functions and properties.

Comment: Project Parallax Abandoned. I tried but couldn't make it work. Thank you @Alex-J for your time. I'm deleting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching the working organized code:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="directives/second-module.js"></script>
  <script src="helper/first-module.js"></script>
  <script src="module.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="duParallax">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
         <input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="onClick()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### JS

1. first-module.js under helper folder

   angular.module("duParallax.helper", []).factory("parallaxHelper", function(){
       return {
           getData : function(){
               return "Sample Service";
           }
       }
   });
2. second-module.js under directive folder

   angular.module("duParallax.directive", []).directive("duParallax", function(){
       return {
           restrict: "A",
           templateUrl: "demo.html"
       }
   });
3. module.js which is under root folder

   angular.module("duParallax", ["duParallax.helper", "duParallax.directive"]).controller("mainController", function($scope, parallaxHelper){
       $scope.onClick = function(){
           console.log(parallaxHelper.getData());
       }
   });
   Try it, will help you.

### Update

1. module.js

   var module = angular.module("duParallax", ["duParallax.helper", "duParallax.directive"]).controller("mainController", function($scope, parallaxHelper){
       $scope.onClick = function(){
           console.log(parallaxHelper.getData());
       }
   });

   angular.module('app',['onsen', module.name]);
2. index.html

   Replace ng-app="duParallax" with ng-app="app"

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Suneet-Bansal but as i said before, i'm already using angular.module('app',['onsen']), if i use duParallax instead of onsen, my program collapses. 'onsen' is mandatory because i'm using OnsenUI framework. Also i use ng-app='app' throughout the page, i don't know whether it's possible to nest ng-app. looking on to it now.

Comment: For that follow the Update section of the above code.

Comment: That three files belong to a [plugin](https://github.com/oblador/angular-parallax), editing them would make them unusable right? however i tried it, but still not working.